# MySql Insertar fila enima de duplicados

Tags: sql, insertar

necesito hacer una inserción un tanto extraña y no doy con la tecla. Me explico, tengo una tabla con varios campos y en el campo ID hay algunos registros que son iguales y otros que son únicos, lo que necesito hacer es que encima del grupo de los duplicados me escriba una fila nueva sólo con el número de ID y los demás vacíos.
Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo que encima del primer registro de los 21646 me agregue una línea completa nueva sólo con el dato 21646.

Comment: 1. Pon en las etiquetas qué base de datos estás utilizando (según el título es _mysql_) y elimina la otra etiqueta, ya que es una [meta-etiqueta](/help/tagging). 2. Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y no olvides que tanto la consulta como los datos de ejemplo deben ir _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: una petición un tanto extraña, el como ingresen los datos muy pocas veces es relevante... si quisiera eso que pides, usaría una consulta con un order by, y listo, sin pelear con eso, porque hasta donde sé, eso que quieres no es posible

Comment: Hola L. Ronquillo, tiene una lógica, estos datos se corresponden con informacion que hay que migrar a un software concreto, la cosa es que esos grupos de números iguales corresponden a la misma familia y el software al que los voy a migrar la única manera que tiene de reconocer que esos datos son hijos de una categoria padre es dejando el mismo ID pero con el resto de campos vacíos, la cosa es que como son muchos registros manualmente se hace muy arduo hacerlo, de ahí que quiera poner encima de cada grupo que se repite una linea con el mismo ID pero el resto de campos vacíos.